# Naive Bayes for Spam detection

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, natural-language, naive-bayes

I am studying few examples of simple Naive Bayes for Spam detection. I had a question it, but I am unable to find it in any of the examples.

I was wondering, what will happen if a word appears multiple times in emails. For example, if we have total of 4 Spam Emails, and they contain the word "Password" 8 times, what will be the probability of P(Password|Spam) then. 
According to the formula they are using in examples, it will become 8/4 = 2, which obviously is not possible, as probability can never be greater than 1. What am I missing, please help.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways how you can use text features in your machine learning algorithms. You can simply encode if a word occurred in the text (coded as 0 - no, 1 - yes), you can use [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) (count their occurrences), using [$n$-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) (combinations of ordered words), [TF-IDF scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), [Word2vec encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec), you can also consider their position in the text and there are many other possible representations. The most simple applications would be to 0-1 encode the occurrence of a word, and then you'd be dealing only with binary features in your naive Bayes algorithm. How do you do it depends on many factors, e.g. if you have a huge dataset you may be more prone to use a more simple method, or if you want to improve the performance of your algorithm, you may consider something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you say where you are getting the examples and formula's from?

Here is an excellent question and answer on Naive Bayes: [Understanding Naive Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/understanding-naive-bayes)

When using Naive Bayes you are not getting a normalized probability distribution, but rather a ranking that is proportional to it.

Taken from the post reference above:

**Bayes Theorem:**

$P(class|features)=\frac{P(features|class)⋅P(class)}{P(features)}$

In Naive Bayes, we don't divide by $P(features)$, giving us:

$P(class|features)∝P(features|class)⋅P(class)$

If I have the data and formulas you are working with I can try to explain it with reference to your problem in particular.